# Issue with C# Web API 2 Date format in JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a large system that is using C# Web API 2 and Angular 12 on the front-end.  Dates that are coming in via Oracle to C# are true dates in both systems (not strings).

They come across in the format "2021-11-10T10:48:38", which is showing `typeof()` as `string` into Angular even though we have these in TypeScript as `Date` in the interface.

When any JS date operations are attempted on these date objects, they fail, although the front-end compiler doesn't catch them because it assumes they are Date types due to the interface.  So it fails at run-time.

What is the best way to handle this on the C# side?   I can do `ourDate = new Date(ourDate)` on the Angular side, which does work, but is not reasonable to do this everywhere we call the API.

I apologize for all the tags but I'm not sure where I should attack this from, I assume in the JSON serialization step on the server.

Comment: Can you give a c# model and controller example? Most of the time the JSON serialization in the request pipeline will take care of all of this for you.

Comment: The issue here is pretty straightforward- JSON does not support actual Date objects as these are not serializable. So this is not really an Angular or js issue. The only proper way to solve this is indeed to convert de serialized date string back to a Date Object everytime on the JS side.

Comment: Additional tip: use UTC/Zulu dates on the serverside always. That will make thing like automatic conversion to correct date/times on the client a lot easier..

Comment: @MikeOne Not my call, it's a legacy system with regards to the DB schema, unfortunately.  I don't see why this can't be handled in the C# serialization pipeline.

Comment: I mean, if that Angular app is properly structured and your http services are concentrated, you can create a custom rxjs pipe to convert any date strings in the incoming responses to proper Date objects there - as close to your API as possible. That will save you going through all components (IF all those components indeed all expect Date objects and not date strings..

Comment: @MikeOne I don't see how this can be handled with a pipe in a service.  If my service is `return this.httpClient.post<ServiceResponse>(url, body).pipe(map(r => r.result as CallReport));` in one instance and that interface has 3 dates that need to be converted, and `r.result as SomeOtherInterface` in another service with 6 dates, how can a generic pipe be created to handle this?  I will have to modify every service.

Comment: If you have a regex that can recognize a date string you can recursively go through your response and replace them. It’s not very nice perse but it is very possible (we’ve done it before). It would technically even be possible to do this in a http interceptor, then you only have to do it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't attack it from the server, since JSON uses ISO 8601 string format to encode dates as a string - the response can't be represented in Typescript with the Date type.
You should have a different type which is just a response DTO only known to the http client layer, and map it to a type known to your service/component.

As a side note, this also leads to better architecture, the domain shouldn't really know or care about the response DTO - it is an implementation detail - imagine tomorrow you'd use a binary serialization or something else.. your domain shouldn't be coupled to the data provider which is a different boundary.